# Help with HTML server request syntax - concat strings

Tags: html, onclick

I am trying to execute a script when a button is pressed on my webpage. Currently the following code works:

```
<input type="button" onclick="newAJAXCommand('focuser1.htm?moveOut=100');" value="Out" style="width: 130px; height: 80px">
```

Instead of sending the hardcoded value of 100 I want to send whatever number is entered in a textbox that is also on the page that looks like this...

```
<input type="text" name="inc" maxlength="10" style="width: 80px" value="10"> <input type="submit" name="setInc" value="Set" style="width: 75px;">
```

So I am sure I have the syntax all wrong but this is basically what I want to do:

```
<input type="button" onclick="newAJAXCommand('focuser1.htm?moveOut=" + document.getElementById('inc').value" ');" value="Out" style="width: 130px; height: 80px">
```

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible

```
<input type="button" onclick="newAJAXCommand('focuser1.htm?moveOut=' + document.getElementById('inc').value);" value="Out" style="width: 130px; height: 80px">
```

Ah, and you need to add id attribute to text input

```
<input type="text" id="inc" maxlength="10" style="width: 80px" value="10">
```

Anyway, I think its better to do such things within function:

```
function newAJAXCommand(url, id)
{
     //do something with url and document.getElementById(id);
}
```